# Using jQuery for setting Local Storage Keys from Input Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

So I'm trying to start on a to do list in html5 + jQuery using Local Storage, but for some odd reason I can't get the jQuery to make a local storage key.

Here is my code. I want it to collect the value of the input box, add it to local storage, and then print the code in the div named.

```
$('#taskEntryForm').submit(function () {

    if ($('#taskInput').val() !== '') {

        var input_value = $('#taskInput').val();
        var stored_input = this.localStorage.setItem('task_',input_value);
        var task = this.localStorage.getItem('task_');
        $('#taskList').append("<br>"+task);


    };

    return false;

});
```

and then the HTML...

```
<html>  
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="shit.js"></script>
</head>   
<div id="cNew">
<form id="taskEntryForm">
<input id="taskInput" name="taskInput" autofocus></form>
</div>
<div id="taskList"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code `this` stands for form. Local storage object is not part of the form, it is a part of `window`. You should change `this` (which represents form) to `window`, or remove `this` at all (because `window.localStorage` is identical to just `localStorage`):

```
$('#taskEntryForm').submit(function () {
    if ($('#taskInput').val() !== '') {
        var input_value = $('#taskInput').val();
        var stored_input = localStorage.setItem('task_',input_value);  // <- removed 'this'
        var task = localStorage.getItem('task_');  // <- removed 'this'
        $('#taskList').append("<br>"+task);
    };
    return false;
});
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pmnp2wx/)